# Reflect.decorate VS decorating manually in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, metaprogramming

I have two decorators as follow:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const enum MetadataTypes {
  Type = "design:type",
  Paramtypes = "design:paramtypes",
  ReturnType = "design:returntype"
}

function Decorator1(target: any, key: string): void {
  console.log(`Applied Decorator1 to ${key} on ${target.constructor.name}`);
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataTypes.Type, target, key);
  console.log(type.name);
}

function Decorator2(target: any, key: string): void {
  console.log(`Applied Decorator2 to ${key} on ${target.name}`);
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataTypes.Type, target, key);
  console.log(type);
}
```

One is applied manually:

```
export class MyClass {
  @Decorator1
  private foo: string;
}
```

and the other using `Reflect.decorate`:

```
Reflect.decorate([Decorator2], MyClass, "foo");
```

Why the decorator applied using Reflect is not able to retrieve the data type?

Logoutput is:

```
Applied Decorator1 to foo on MyClass
String

Applied Decorator2 to foo on MyClass
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve similar behaviour with `Reflect.decorate`, you have to pass the prototype of the class.

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const enum MetadataTypes {
  Type = "design:type",
  Paramtypes = "design:paramtypes",
  ReturnType = "design:returntype"
}

function Decorator1(target: any, key: string): void {
  console.log(`Applied Decorator1 to ${key} on ${target.constructor.name}`);
  const type = Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataTypes.Type, target, key);
  console.log(type.name);
}

export class MyClass {
  private foo: string;
}

Reflect.decorate([Decorator1], MyClass.prototype, "foo");

// Output:
// Applied Decorator1 to foo on MyClass
// undefined
```

The problem is that the metadata is not generated when `Reflect.decorate` is used.

Using a decorator syntax makes the compiler save metadata (when `emitDecoratorMetadata` is config option enabled) that can be accessed via `Reflect.getMetadata`.

You can read about it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2577